# Relative gluing over two schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01LG they construct a scheme over $X$ which is obtained by gluing schemes over basic open subsets of $X$ satisfying some conditions.

Is there a similar way to construct a scheme over two schemes. More precisely given schemes $X \rightarrow Z$ and $Y \rightarrow Z$ and and schemes $W_{U,V}\rightarrow U\hookrightarrow X$, $W_{U,V}\rightarrow V\hookrightarrow Y$ satisfying "certain data" to give a scheme $W$ such that the square commutes?. In some sense I'm asking for the minimal data required to show the existence of fiber product.

I understand that I haven't formuated the question properly. But, any suggestions would help.